# Permutation group of objects which are themselves permutations

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

I am looking for a way to describe permutation groups, say $S_n$, where the permuted elements are not simple numbers but symmetric pairs of numbers. So, in some sense this is the "$S_n$ power of $S_2$". I know the order of these groups, but I will need them in terms of cycles.

The context of this question is tensor calculation in physics. We express the order parameter of nematic material by a symmetric rank-2 tensor, and then take higher powers of this to describe all possible deformations of the material. I want to automatise this step in a computer program. For this I need the different conjugacy classes of the permutation group of the indices, their number of elements, and how they decompose into cycles.

If anyone could point me to a reference or drop me some hints where to find such a "power" of two permutation groups, please let me know.

From the first comment I learn that I must be more specific -- Here is an example of $S_2$ and $S_4$: The combined group (for which I do not know the proper name) can be generated by understanding `(1,2,3,4,5,7,8)` as four successive pairs, and then permute within each pair, and permute the pairs. So, the group can be generated by the following exchanges:

```
(12), (34), (56), (78) : switch within one of the four pairs
(13)(24), (15)(26), (17)(28) : exchange pairs
```

The resulting group has 20 conjugacy classes (already this I find nontrivial). Each of them has a "pattern" of cycle lengths. By this I mean that the identity element can be expressed as (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8), thus 8 cycle lengths of one. The element (12)(34)(56)(78) has 4 cycle lengths of two. Elements such as (12) have 6 cycle lengths of one and 1 cycle of length two. When we continue like this, we get the following table of cycle lengths:

```
class(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8):  1 elements, cycle lengths: [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
class(2 1 4 3 6 5 8 7):  1 elements, cycle lengths: [0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
class(2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8):  4 elements, cycle lengths: [6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
class(1 2 4 3 6 5 8 7):  4 elements, cycle lengths: [2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
class(2 1 3 4 5 6 8 7):  6 elements, cycle lengths: [4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
class(8 7 3 4 5 6 2 1): 12 elements, cycle lengths: [4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
class(1 2 5 6 4 3 7 8): 12 elements, cycle lengths: [4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
class(4 3 2 1 6 5 8 7): 12 elements, cycle lengths: [0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
class(2 1 6 5 3 4 8 7): 12 elements, cycle lengths: [0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
class(3 4 1 2 8 7 6 5): 12 elements, cycle lengths: [0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
class(6 5 7 8 1 2 4 3): 12 elements, cycle lengths: [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
class(2 1 3 4 7 8 5 6): 24 elements, cycle lengths: [2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
class(1 2 4 3 8 7 5 6): 24 elements, cycle lengths: [2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
class(7 8 5 6 4 3 1 2): 24 elements, cycle lengths: [0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
class(5 6 2 1 4 3 7 8): 32 elements, cycle lengths: [2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
class(3 4 6 5 1 2 7 8): 32 elements, cycle lengths: [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
class(3 4 8 7 6 5 2 1): 32 elements, cycle lengths: [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
class(3 4 7 8 6 5 2 1): 32 elements, cycle lengths: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
class(5 6 8 7 3 4 2 1): 48 elements, cycle lengths: [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
class(7 8 2 1 3 4 5 6): 48 elements, cycle lengths: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

In some sense, this is the "product" of $S_2$ and $S_4$, which have the tables of cycle lengths as follows:

```
class(1 2): 1 element, cycle lengths: [2, 0]
class(2 1): 1 element, cycle lengths: [0, 1]
```

```
class(1 2 3 4): 1 element, cycle lengths: [4, 0, 0, 0]
class(4 3 2 1): 3 element, cycle lengths: [0, 2, 0, 0]
class(4 2 3 1): 6 element, cycle lengths: [2, 1, 0, 0]
class(2 4 1 3): 6 element, cycle lengths: [0, 0, 0, 1]
class(2 3 1 4): 8 element, cycle lengths: [1, 0, 1, 0]
```

The above tables are taken from a computer code that generates the whole group, identifies the classes, etc. My question is: Can I deduce the long table directly from the small ones, without generating the whole group?

Comment: I'm not sure from your description exactly what you mean, but the wreath product of two symmetric groups may be of interest.

Comment: Then you are indeed looking at a wreath product. The account of these in Dixon's "Permutation Groups" I found quite accessible as an introduction. That, though, is just a name for what you are looking at.

Comment: I updated my question. Thank you for the hint with the wrath product, and for the reference. I will see into it.